# USB ports fail to recognize on wake

Tags: windows-7, usb, sleep, hibernate

Whenever I hibernate or sleep my computer -- and then wake it up, all USB ports don't recognize anything. For example, my usb printer will not recognize, my phone will say it's charging (but not connected via MTP), my usb mouse has power (indicated by led) but won't work, etc.

At first I thought it was because the system was suspending the ports, but even when I disabled it via power options, it's still doing the same thing.

[image]

I get this within my device manager:

[image]

I have USB2.0 drivers installed, and they work fine when I reboot, but any time I resume from hibernation or sleep, all usb ports fail.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

> Right click and update your driver which would fix this issue

Else

> uninstall and reinstall the updated driver

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a BIOS update. Sounds really like a BIOS bug.
If you look on Details, you will propably see that VID and PID is propably incorrect (not what it was Before the computer hibernated), thus windows is "asking for drivers" even tough the device's drivers are fully installed.

Answer (score 0):

in my case same as your USB my sound are disabled then identified that in the GPEDIT menus are changes.
if this problem is there then try this

```
Go To >RUN or WINDOWS + R

Then Tpe "GPEDIT.MSC" (without ")

search Auto-run USB disable 

Enable it.....:)
```

Comment: Please take a moment to [familiarize yourself](http://superuser.com/editing-help) with Markdown, look at the preview window before posting. Most of your answers are extremely poorly formatted and makes it hard to understand

Comment: sorry for that bro. but I am new in this so.....:(